# Propagating mouse events from iframes to the hosting document

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

I have an iframe covering the entire HTML document, and I'd like to propagate clicks and hover events back to the hosting document.

What are my options?

Comment: What *information* to you want to send to the hosting document?

Comment: Eww. Why would you setup an iframe to replace the page?

Comment: Also, you should start marking questions as answered (the green outline checkmark under the best answer's vote tally). This helps get better answers. 17% isn't good for 17 questions.

Answer (score 3):

I was asked to look into this several weeks ago for a project. It's possible to do it, and there's a working example of it in action here:

http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/iframe_talks_to_parent/

However, the crucial thing to bear in mind is that unless the parent and child are on the same domain, it's not possible to have events passed between them. If your iframe contains a page from a different domain then you're out of luck, I think.

Comment: Exactly. You have to control the code in both the parent and child in order for them to talk. If the child is another domain you are out of luck as you will have no way to add the required code to make it work.